# Using Moles to watch Powershell usage by Windows GUI programs

Tags: powershell-3.0, moles, setwindowshookex

One response to my question about [generating Powershell code by working in the Windows GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459077/generating-powershell-scripts-by-working-in-windows-gui) pointed out that the Windows GUI code is calling into the managed `system.management.automation` library.

Would it be possible to use Moles in a DLL I write that could hook into calls being made by Windows GUI programs to those "automation" APIs? It probably would only work if the DLL gets installed via a system-wide "Windows hook" (so that it is within the GUI program's address space).

I'm quite certain that I don't have the knowledge to do this quickly, but I personally think that this would be a killer feature -- one that MS could build more easily than we can, but they don't seem to have done this except in specific products (like System Center). Does anyone think it could be done -- by someone with the right skills -- within a relatively short time (and perhaps that they'd like to try it)?

Any thoughts?